# Django if tag not evaluating equality

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-views

I have got a big JSON object (from Google Feed API) and a URL from context. When ever the URL from context is same as in a feed entry URL, django should parse!

```
{for aEntry in feed.entries %}
{% if aEntry.link == {{my_URL}} %}

<p>URL FOUND in feed entry</p>
{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

This is not working!!

**Edit:**

```
feed: {
            "feedUrl": "http://.blogspot.in//feeds/posts/default",
            "title": "",
            "link": "http://.blogspot.com/",
            "author": "",
            "description": "",
            "type": "atom10",
            "entries": [{
                "title": "Shades",
                "link": "http://.blogspot.com/myurl.html",
                "author": "",
                "publishedDate": "Sun, 29 Jul 2012 04:07:00 -0700",
                "contentSnippet": "abstract art!",
                "content": " HTML CONTENT HERE",
                "categories": ["abstract"]
            }

context = { "feed" : feed, "my_url" : "http://.blogspot.com/myurl.html"}
```

Comment: @anhtran yeah, so do `{{my_URL}}`

Comment: @anhtran oops. its mistake in this question.. corrected !

Comment: Could you post the pattern of JSON from Google Feed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
{% if "aEntry.link" == {{my_URL}} %}
```

needs to be

```
{% ifequal aEntry.link my_URL %}
```

Comment: its not working. actually that's a small typo in my question!

Comment: {{my_URL}} also needs to loose the brackets

Comment: Exactly -- inside of the if statement, you can refer to context variables; the `{{}}` syntax is to insert them into the HTML of the response.